# How do I add a score to this game

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to figure out how to add a score to this for ages. I'm still not sure ;( sorry I'm new to coding.

this is the code for the main part

```
while roundsPlayed > 0:
    chips_left = MAX_CHIPS
    n = 1
    rounds = 1
    while chips_left > 0:
        while True:
            print("Number of chips left {}".format(chips_left))
            if n%2 == 0:
                print("{} How many chips would you like to take (1 - 3):  ".format(playerTwo))
            else:
                print("{} How many chips would you like to take (1 - 3):  ".format(playerOne))
            
            
            try:
                chipsTaken = int(input())
                if chipsTaken < 1 or chipsTaken > 3:
                    print("Please enter a valid number from 1 to 3!")
                
                else:
                    break
            except:
                print("Thats not even a number brotherman")
        n += 1
        
        

        chips_left = chips_left - chipsTaken

    roundsPlayed = roundsPlayed - 1
    rounds += 1
```

Comment: Where would this score show and what would be the its use or purpose?

Comment: oh basically the person who gets to 0 first wins and I want it to keep count so if they play 3 rounds it will after first round it will be like Player1 wins score : player1 - 1
player2 - 0

Comment: In the line with `input`, do you currently somehow keep track about which player is currently managing the chips i.e. whose chip count is affected by the current input? Or is this entire code you are showing somehow affecting only one player?

Comment: By person who gets to 0, do you mean the person that takes the last available chip in a round ? You can make 2 score variables, and increment one of them at the end of the loop for each round. I'll write an example if i've understood it correctly.
Also, what is the `rounds` variable meant for ? Since you've created it _inside_ the first while loop, it'll keep resetting to 1 each time.